# Find text in string and replace with another in JavaScript

Tags: jquery

My html:

```
<span data-sample="http://mysite.com"></span>
```

My JS:

```
 var objLink = $(this).attr('data-sample');
```

Hence my `objLink == "http://mysite.com"`

How can I add "www" and make the `objLink == "http://www.mysite.com"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is the answer you are looking for, but you can use `.replace()` to do this.

```
objLink = objLink.replace("http://", "http://www.");
```

Check the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XZKaj/

Comment: And if you want to apply it back to the span, use `$(this).attr('data-sample', objLink);`

Comment: If you satisfied with the answer you will need to accept it. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: Or `.replace("://", "://www.")` if you want to allow for potential `https` links. Maybe add a condition to only do the replace if the url doesn't already have "www" in it...